# React-Native Flashing white when switching to a new page (Android)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

How can I solve this problem?

[Problem Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l_u1xJ7JgTs)

[Version numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CQFZ.png)

Comment: Are you doing some heavy stuff on next screen?

Comment: Please update with your navigation or these screen codes.

Comment: Pages are blank. The project is already new.